# How do I find out which wallet fits which client?

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat

I found a really old Bitcoin wallet, a `wallet.dat` file, and tried to open it. Bitcoin Core told me that the wallet is corrupted. But I also found out that different clients make different wallets, so they aren't supposed to be compatible with each other. How do I find out which client I need to use to be able to open this wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core is the only software that uses a file called `wallet.dat`, as far as I know.

Comment: I think Armory uses the same... Also many derivatives use the same name, as well.

Comment: Besides, several -salvagewallet tries didn't work out at all. The hard drive is perfectly fine and I don't see **any** reason for the wallet to be actually corrupted.

Comment: Armory uses armory_{name}.wallet.

Comment: The only software that uses wallet.dat is anything that is based on Bitcoin Core (e.g. Bitcoin XT, Bitcoin Classic, Bitcoin Unlimited, btc1) and altcoins that have forked from Core at some point (basically all altcoins).

Comment: This is horrible, I use some wallets of coins that are forked of Bitcoin, and suddenly I find a wallet.dat on my d:\ drive, not knowing for which coin it is...